# IOS/Objective-C: Detect if nsmanaged object linked to another nsmanagedobject in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I allow comments on different types of items in my app such as books and songs. To link the comment to the item, I create a relationship in core data.

Then to put the name of the item, ie a book, next to the comment I use the relationship.  For a book title, I can use `comment.book.title` to get the title.

However, for a book the title will be `comment.book.title` but for a song, the title will be `comment.song.title`.  For some comments, I created a relationship to a certain book and in others to a certain song.  It is true that there is a formal relationship between the entities and attributes in Core Data. But I'm getting confused about those underlying relationships and the specific ones I create to make the association.

My immediate need is to  detect if a relationship has been established.

Comments has one relationship `book` to books and another `song` to songs.

Should I use something like if

```
if (comment.book.title.length>=1) {
myLabel.text = comment.book.title;
}
else if (comment.song.title.length>=1) {
myLabel.text= comment.song.title;
}
```

Or what is the best way to do this?

**Edit/Clarification:**

The above code seems to work.  Not sure if it is robust, however.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should work just fine. If you want something more generic, Core Data actually supports inheritance and abstract classes.

So you could make your Book and Song object inherit from a Content abstract super class. That class would hold common attributes between all subclasses, such as title, and a relationship to the Comment entity.

Here's a diagram of what I just said.

[image]

Then, to check get the title of the whatever the comment is related to, you just do: `comment.content.title`.